# Ensure parent component receives the ultimate child state via props callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Behind the scenes react optimizes `useState` by using different techniques (among others) like batching, scheduling and even discarding some `useState` calls if the value hasn't changed.

I've run into a scenario where I'm not sure if, eventually, parent component will receive the same value as the child's internal state after react has finished updating it.

There is a stateful `Item` component, that can be added to favorites. This component, besides keeping internal state, accepts a callback prop `onFavoritesChange` for the other components to know when the state changes.

In its simplest form the component looks like the following

```
const Item = ({onFavoritesChange}) => {
  const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);

  const onFavoritesChangeHandler = () => {
    const toggle = !isFavorite;
    setIsFavorite(toggle)
    onFavoritesChange?.(toggle)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onFavoritesChangeHandler}>
        {isFavorite ? 'Add to' : 'Remove from'} favorites
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Option #1** In the above example it seems like it works very predictably, and it will probably deliver the desired result

```
const onFavoritesChangeHandler = () => {
  const toggle = !isFavorite;
  setIsFavorite(toggle)
  onFavoritesChange?.(toggle)
}
```

**Option #2** But since the new state depends on the previous state, it's better to use a callback version of `useState`

```
const onFavoritesChangeHandler = () => {
  setIsFavorite(prev => !prev);
  onFavoritesChange?.(!isFavorite)
}
```

This is actually what's bothering me. The parent will receive a new value, and upon receiving it will be correct. But when react will have updated the state (via `prev => !prev` callback) I assume it might be different (assuming the button will be hammered with clicks)

**Option #3** Having this situation, the most obvious solution to me was this

```
const onFavoritesChangeHandler = () => {
  setIsFavorite(prev => {
    const toggle = !prev;
    onFavoritesChange?.(toggle)
    return toggle;  
  })
}
```

Even though it does the trick, it doesn't seem right to use it this way, nor I have seen done it this way

Answer (score 0):

I think useEffect might do the trick

```
useEffect(() => {
  onFavoritesChange?.(isFavorite)
}, [isFavorite]);
```

Comment: Isn't it going to call the callback on the first run? The idea behind the callback is to be run when the button is clicked only.

Comment: Using `useEffect` it invokes `onFavoritesChange` when the component is first mounted and the button hasn't been clicked yet

Comment: In that case just use the state from parent component. It seams like you don't need local state at all

Comment: I guess it makes sense. Thanks